# How to use background downloader to download image in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I want to download image from a URL in windows phone 8.1 and I use `BackgroundDownloader` for it, but it does not work, can anyone please help me?

```
var source = new Uri(source_image, UriKind.Absolute);
string LocalName = "10oswall";
var destinationFile =
    await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync(
        LocalName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
var downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(source, destinationFile);

download.Priority = BackgroundTransferPriority.High;
await download.StartAsync();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: it run but i did not see my image in cell phone lib

Comment: Have you debugged it? Are any exceptions thrown by the download? Also note the documentation explicitly states that `BackgroundDownloader` is for large files (like videos) and not small files (like images) - you probably should just do this with an `HttpClient`.